# Mapbox Geocoding custom address

Tags: mapbox, geocoding

I would like to add custom addresses to Mapbox Geocoding search bar,
but I could not find any examples in Mapbox's official tutorials for that.

I use my original codes (e.g. #abc1234) to point a corresponding coordinate (longitude, latitude) in my project. The coordinates are calculated from the codes systematically and the number of codes is enormous, so, to be exact I want to install an algorithm (not addresses) to Mapbox Geocoding, enter a code in search bar and get a corresponding address.

Is there a way to do that?